# How do you make a property truly read only?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, readonly

Take the following property:

```
public string Foo
{
   get;
   private set;
}
```

Using reflection, I can still set the value of this property from outside the owning class.  Is there a way to prevent this?  Removing the set accessor is not an option as it must be WCF friendly.

Comment: Could you throw an exception in your setter? I've used this strategy to prevent using reflection to re-instantiate a singleton object (in Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Skeet [says](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2196297.php):

> You can't (AFAIK) stop reflection being used in a situation where the
>   caller has "full trust". If they're running with less than full trust
>   then some things about reflection (if not all) are automatically
>   disabled, I believe - however, if this is to stop other people from
>   calling some code, you can't prevent them from running your code *with*
>   full trust unless you're in control of their box in the first place.

Comment: [ReflectionPermission(SecurityAction.Deny, Flags = ReflectionPermissionFlag.AllFlags)] is about all i can think of, but it may not really help

Answer (score 4):

A really ugly solution would be to use the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class to verify that only methods from your own class calls the setter.

Answer (score 2):

You could obfuscate the code. This would make it hard to reflect on it.